# Django : How do I send HTTP request through POST not using form

Tags: django, http, post

I have the following code in one of my template pages

```
<h4 id="upvote">
  <a href="/post/{{post.id}}/vote/1">Up</a>
</h4>
<h4 id="downvote">
  <a href="/post/{{post.id}}/vote/0">Down</a>
</h4>
```

At the moment, I'm not using a form but I wish to send these by HTTP POST

Do I need to use a form to do that or can it be done without one?

Comment: If you want to avoid a form (which I see no reason to use for such a simple case), use an AJAX request.
How to do that, you can check jQuery `$.ajax` and also CSRF protection in Django Ajax:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: Hmm.. I have absolutely no experience in ajax or javascript other than a simple alert... is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: Simpler than an ajax request? I believe not...

Comment: Once you learn it, everything becomes simple..

Comment: Ok I guess I will have a go at this. Thank you for the comment. If you want, please make it an answer so I can accept it since you gave me a working solution ;)

Comment: @karthikr I guess so lol. Java seemed so hard but now I love it

Comment: Simpler than a Ajax is *to use a form*. You haven't given any reason for why you would not want to do the obvious thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I would use jQuery and its post method. This makes an ajax call to the server using POST without having to reload the page. (jQuery takes a little bit to learn but is soooo much easier to then JavaScript because of its shortcuts)

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/post/{{post.id}}/vote/1",
    success: function(){
        //Do something here that lets the user know things worked out
    }
});
```

If you are not inclined to using jQuery you can make the same type of call using normal JavaScript, though it has a little bit more to it in my oppinion.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost2.shtml

Either way this could be applied to a button's "onclick" event and then the response could be handled and processed before being returned to the user. i.e. let the user know if the request was successful or failed.

EDIT:
Not sure why you need a post for that it looks like because all of the data is contained in the URL and nothing is being sent along as part of the header, you could simply use a GET request.

Comment: Just a quick side question, would I need to learn some js before learning jquery? I have some experience in JAVA.. I don't know if that helps..

Comment: He should stick to POST because voting alters the data of the model, GET should be restricted only to non altering data requests.

Comment: @Dan You may want to learn JavaScript. It took me a few hours to get a handle on the language. If you are developing on the web a lot I would suggest learning it regardless along with css.

Comment: @petkostas I agree POST is the correct way to handle this though GET *could* be used.